# Method to calculate complex residuals between a complex function and data containing real and imaginary parts

Tags: r, data-fitting, nls

I am working on building a script in RStudio which can fit Complex Impedance data of the form Z = a + ib, to model formulas which aim to describe how Z changes with frequency.  I have seen for other languages that a good route to go about this is by minimising the residuals between the complex values predicted and the complex values recorded as data. I am a little confused about how to actually implement this in R. Is there are a general route to do this in R?

Apologies for not providing more example code - I have encoded the functions and loaded my data but past this I am not really sure what to do.

A typical function is of the form:

```r
ZRC <- function(R2, C1)((R2)/(1+1*i*R2*w*C1))
```

Where w is recorded from the data.
I tried forming a function which is the difference between this and the data Z and then minimising this using nls():

```r
diff <- function(R1, R2, C1)(Z - (R2)/(1+1*i*R2*w*C1))

model1 <- nls(diff~0, start = list(R1 = 10, R2 = 100, C1 = 1E-6))
```

But this gave an error message saying object is not a matrix

Comment: Can you include a typical value of `w` (e.g. output of `dput()`) in your example?  (You probably need to write a function that computes `sum(Mod(predicted-observed))` [or sum of squared moduli] and pass it to `optim()` ...

Comment: So w is a variable ranging from 100000 to 0.1. The data I reference above is w (the frequency at which the measurement is taken), and then the real and imaginary component of the response. The conventional way to process this data is to plot the real and imaginary component against eachother, and then fit this plot with a model. The problem I am finding is that the models give expressions for total Z, and I am trying to fit to a graph with the real and imaginary components of Z at each w. Thank you for the suggestion !! Any more help is very much appreciated:)

Comment: I tried to write this as: `sumsq <- sum(Mod(function(R1, R2, C1)(R1 + ((R2)/(1+((1i)*R2*w*C1)))) - Z)))

optim(par = list(R1 = 10, R2 = 10, C1 = 0.00001), fn = sumsq)` , but got an error saying non-numeric argument to function - I'm not really sure how to change this to get rid of the error

Comment: I don't understand, but maybe you rather want `sumsq <- function(R1, R2, C1) { Mod( ...... ) }`.

Comment: If the "traditional method" is to handle the real and imaginary separately, wouldn't you also need some criterion for assessing the goodness of fit that combines the two "residual" so that you can decide what is "best"? Sounds like you also have some sort of "target" or perhaps two targets? There are both a `Re` and an `Im` function in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but you will probably be best off writing a function that computes the sum of the moduli (or the sum of squares of the moduli) and passing that to `optim()` to minimize, something like:

```r
## Z, w are global variables in this example
sum_mod_fun <- function(p) {
    ## parameters must be specified as a vector; unpack them
    R1 <- p[1]; R2 <- p[2]; C1 <- p[3]
    pred <- R1 + R2/(1+(1i*R2*w*C1))  ## check formula!
    return(sum(Mod(pred-Z)^2))
}
optim(fn = sum_mod_fun, 
      par = c(R1 = 10, R2 = 10, C1 = 0.00001))
## note, in this example parameter vector must be in the right order - not checked!
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this almost works. I am getting 'function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters' even though the initial parameters I have put in are roughly correct - is there an obvious reason why this is? Also, I don't really understand the specifying the parameters as a vector step - does this code do this or do I need to make: ``` p <- c("R1", "R2", "C1")? Apologies, thank you for all of your help so far!

Comment: Thank you! I think this worked and I was being stupid.